# Classic ASP not picking up AJAX POST data

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp-classic

I'm having trouble receiving data from an AJAX POST request in classic ASP using Request.Form. Here's my code at it's simplest. It returns nothing.

First page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $.ajax({
                url: "test1.asp",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "plain",
                data: { name: "Hello" },
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Second page: (test1.asp)

```
<%
    Response.Write Request.Form("name")
%>
```

If I call the second page using a standard HTML form instead of AJAX, it picks it up with no problem eg:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form id="thisForm" method="POST" action="test1.asp">
            <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Hello"/>
        </form>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("thisForm").submit();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there something wrong with my code or could this be a server config issue?

Comment: did you see on the debug browser if the call ajax to the ASP page test1.asp is called or no? and the "Second page" is test1.asp?

Comment: What happens if you omit the `contentType` and `dataType` ?

Comment: I can see that test1.asp has been called. The request payload says 'name=Hello' and there is no response.

Comment: I still get nothing if I remove the contentType and dataType.

Comment: Your best bet is the F12 key to start the developer tools of your browser, check the network tab to see if the call is sent, and what the response is.

Comment: @Erik Oosterwaal - Yes, I've looked at the dev tools and as said above, I can see that test1.asp is being called and I can see that in the request tab, it shows the request payload as 'name=Hello'.

Answer (score -1):

you're specifying json as your data format, but your response from the server is not json. what if you try:

```
Response.Write "{""myName"":""" & Request.Form("name") & """}"
```

and your JS is now:

```
success: function(data) {
   alert(data.myName);
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm very much mistaken, the contentType is the data type of the data that you're sending the ajax request, which in this case is json, the dataType that I'm specifying for the data that's returned is 'plain', I've also tried 'text'. I've made the modifications that you suggest and all I get alerted is 'undefined'. The problem isn't with how the ajax is interpreting the returned data because in my browser dev tools, I can see that test1.asp is returning nothing.

Comment: do you get anything if, on test1.asp, you hard code a value to be written out?

Comment: Yes, if I hard code a response in test1.asp, I do get it sent back to the other page. The problem is with test1.asp picking up the posted data.

Comment: it would be helpful if you could post the entire source code of the page. Or if it is a lot of code, then create an example (on jsFiddle or something closely related) so we can see everything that is going on

Comment: Hi Josh, this is the entire code. Both are complete .asp files.

Answer (score -2):

contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"를 제거하고 시도해보세요.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).